# `.fullScreenCover` is called every time there is an update, and it breaks state of the presented View

Tags: swiftui, dependency-injection, navigation

When `isPresent` is set to `true` the `SomeViewModel` is initiated for the first time, and `SomeView` is presented for the first time.

While `SomeView` is presented, `mainViewModel.text` changes, and it triggers an update to the `MainView` body; Which causes `SomeView` to be called again, thus creating a new `ViewModel` and losing the previous state.

What is the right approach to handle such things?
Am I doing it wrong?

```
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    @State var isPresent: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(mainViewModel.text)
            Button("press me", action: {
                isPresent = true
            })
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresent) {
            ViewsFactory.someView()
        }
    }
}

struct ViewsFactory {
    static func someView() -> some View {
        SomeView(viewModel: SomeViewModel(DI1, DI2, DI3, DI4))
    }
}
```

Comment: `@StateObject` of the `SomeViewModel` or the whole `SomeView`?

Comment: I mistyped before "The only safe way to initialize a, `ObservableObject` in a `View` is with `StateObject`. That ViewFactory is unsafe" https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app My guess is that the source for `MainViewModel` is also not a `StateObject`

Comment: [This](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/dependency-injection/) is a great article on how to use DI with SwiftUI

Comment: From I read so far, `@ObservedObject` should be used when the VM is injected, and `@StateObject` when the object is initiated there. 

The DI blog post looks promising. Thank you.

Comment: No `StateObject` is for initializing and `ObservedObject` is for passing around the biggest issue is lifecycle retention. `ObservedObject` can't maintain state (your state is "breaking") there are other ways of initializing `ObservableObject`s but those ways have to manage lifecycle most notable example is CoreData objects.

Comment: If you look at the “Instsntiate Model Object In a View” paragraph of the link above you’ll see apple’s explanation.

Comment: The article you linked is great. So you so much.

Answer (score 1):

> I think that's to be expected.

---

The `body` will be created every time `eventListViewModel` changed. And the `fullScreenCover` , you can think it and it's subviews as part of the `body`.
And I wrote a demo code as below:

```swift
class Time: ObservableObject {
    @Published var second = 0

    init(second: Int = 0) {
        self.second = second
    }

    func start() {
        Task {
            for _ in 0 ... 999 {
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1000000000)
                second += 1
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @StateObject private var time = Time()
    @State private var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("\(time.second)")
        }
        .onAppear {
            time.start()
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            isPresented = true
        }
        .padding()
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            Text("\((0 ... 1000).randomElement() ?? 0)")
                .onTapGesture {
                    isPresented = false
                }
        }
    }
}
```

the `time` will change every one second which will cause ContentView2's `body` property re-render every one second. `fullScreenCover` display a `Text` which shows a random number. if the `fullScreenCover` is presented, you will see the text changes every one second. So how to avoid this "issue" ?
Here's code:

```swift
class Time: ObservableObject {
    @Published var second = 0

    init(second: Int = 0) {
        self.second = second
    }

    func start() {
        Task {
            for _ in 0 ... 999 {
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1000000000)
                second += 1
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TimeView: View {
    @StateObject private var time = Time()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("\(time.second)")
        }
        .onAppear {
            time.start()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        TimeView()
        .onTapGesture {
            isPresented = true
        }
        .padding()
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            Text("\((0 ... 1000).randomElement() ?? 0)")
                .onTapGesture {
                    isPresented = false
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Extract the view with timer into a new view will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed this as well, something may have changed after an update. I fixed this behavior by going to my outermost view (i.e. the one first used in the Application struct) and attaching it from an empty view. This stopped the redraws (also observed when adding a breakpoint to the .fullScreenCover viewBuilder).

```
# example of Application: App struct
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        AppView()
    }
}

# example of AppView: View
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Spacer()
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresent) {
                Text("test")
            }
        // the rest of the app here
    }
}
```

As opposed to having all kinds of views before the fullScreenCover call which may have been causing cascading redraws. Maybe use zstack and put the Color.clear first with manual zIndex calls.